# Gravitational teleport failing to record sessions on nodes

Tags: session, ansible, record, teleport

I have been using ansible Playbooks to set up a teleport cluster. As of right now I have a cluster set up with 4 nodes (one of which acts as a proxy and auth server). For some reason when I try to playback the recorded sessions, they are all blank except for sessions on the Auth server. All sessions on the nodes show up on the log but when I attempt to play them they are just zero second recordings of nothing. I thought maybe it had something to do with the config file but I was unable to notice anything.

NOTE: below are the config files for the nodes and auth server. I have replaced some information with (Fake...)

Nodes Config file

```
teleport:                                                                                                                                                    
  nodename: (Fake node name)                                                                                                                                          
  pid_file: /var/run/teleport.pid                                                                                                                            

  auth_token: (Fake Auth token)                                                                                                                                        
  auth_servers:                                                                                                                                              
    - 192.168.1.121                                                                                                                                          
  connection_limits:                                                                                                                                         
    max_connections: 1000                                                                                                                                    
    max_users: 250                                                                                                                                           
  log:                                                                                                                                                       
    output: stderr                                                                                                                                           
    severity: WARN                                                                                                                                           
  storage:                                                                                                                                                   
    type: bolt                                                                                                                                               
  data_dir: /var/lib/teleport                                                                                                                                
auth_service:                                                                                                                                                
  enabled: "no"                                                                                                                                              
ssh_service:                                                                                                                                                 
  enabled: "yes"                                                                                                                                             
  listen_addr: 0.0.0.0:3022                                                                                                                                  
proxy_service:                                                                                                                                               
  enabled: "no"
```

Teleport Auth config file

```
teleport:                                                                                                                                                    
  nodename: (Fake Node Name)                                                                                                                                    
  pid_file: /var/run/teleport.pid                                                                                                                            

  auth_token: (fake token)                                                                                                                                        
  auth_servers:                                                                                                                                              
    - 127.0.0.1:3025                                                                                                                                         
  connection_limits:                                                                                                                                         
    max_connections: 1000                                                                                                                                    
    max_users: 250                                                                                                                                           
  log:                                                                                                                                                       
    output: stderr                                                                                                                                           
    severity: WARN                                                                                                                                           
  storage:                                                                                                                                                   
    type: bolt                                                                                                                                               
  data_dir: /var/lib/teleport                                                                                                                                
auth_service:                                                                                                                                                
  enabled: "yes"                                                                                                                                             
  listen_addr: 0.0.0.0:3025                                                                                                                                  
  oidc_connectors: []                                                                                                                                        
  cluster_name: main                                                                                                                                         
  tokens:                                                                                                                                                    
    - "node:(Fake token)"                                                                                                                                         
ssh_service:                                                                                                                                                 
  enabled: "yes"                                                                                                                                             
  listen_addr: 0.0.0.0:3022                                                                                                                                  
proxy_service:                                                                                                                                               
  enabled: "yes"                                                                                                                                             
  listen_addr: 0.0.0.0:3023                                                                                                                                  
  web_listen_addr: 0.0.0.0:3080                                                                                                                              
  tunnel_listen_addr: 0.0.0.0:3024
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not programming-related.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, for some reason my auth server was on an older version of teleport than my nodes.